# UISearchBar disappears on click

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I want to add a search bar under the navigation bar with UISearchController. Here is what I did:

```
SearchResultsTableViewController *resultsVC = [[SearchResultsTableViewController alloc] init];
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:resultsVC];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;

UISearchBar *searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
[searchBar sizeToFit];
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

[self.view addSubview:searchBar];
searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [searchBar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor],
    [searchBar.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor],
    [searchBar.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor],
    [searchBar.heightAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToConstant:0]
]];
```

However, whenever I click the bar, it disappears.
If I hide the navigation bar with the following:

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;
```

It is still not working. And not only that, after navigation bar moves off the screen, there is a black bar at the top. What I am doing wrong here?
[image]